# @fortawesome/Angular-FontAwesome npm package with ng-packagr

Tags: angular, ng-packagr, angular-fontawesome

We create for our angular projects a private npm UI package which contains our UI components. Now I tried to add all our needed Icons from FontAwesome to the Library. We use the ng-packagr to generate the npm package this works without any issue. If I our package then I get a build issue:

Error during template compile of 'WebUiModule'
Could not resolve @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome relative to [object Object].

Our idea is that we define all our needed Icons at the UI npm package an use only the ones we defined there.